# Mongoose consumes a lot of memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

At the start of my express server, I have the following piece of code, getting the approximate heap memory used in the application:

```
const heapMemory = Math.round((process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024) * 10);
console.log(heapMemory + 'MB');
```

After starting the server, I had quite a number of routes and the heap memory, on average was `110MB`. However, I persisted the `mongoose.connect` method and the heap memory jumped to `900MB` on average.

My question is the following:

1. Is it ideal to persist a mongoose connection for the lifetime of the application, or is it better to connect whenever we need it
2. How can we reduce the memory footprint being consumed by `mongoose` (I'm assuming the 810MB difference is being consumed solely by my dear friend mongoose

Comment: Mongoose is intended to be used with persistent connection. It's impossible to say what's wrong without knowing all the details. It's more likely that this is user error rather than a memory leak in the library itself. Any way, if you're able to replicate the problem apart from web server with synthetic db you are able to share with the community, consider opening an issue in Mongoose repo. *I'm assuming the 810MB difference is being consumed solely by my dear friend mongoose* - that's not known for sure since you didn't profile the app.

Comment: @estus, how can I profile the application?

Comment: Google 'node memory profile'.

Comment: I tried, and didn't get anything that could help me reduce the footprint. The amazing thing is that I just switched the Mongoose ORM to another ORM and it took around 3MB extra (instead of the 810MB). So I'll submit it to the mongoose community. Thanks for your help @estus

Comment: @cr05s19xx which ORM did you pick? I'm facing similar issues